# Apache Solr - Error loading class solr.NestPathField for solr version 6.5

Tags: solr, lucene, solrnet, solr6

Trying to have nested child documents inside managed schema in solr 6.5 as -

```
<fieldType name="_nest_path_" class="solr.NestPathField"/> 
<field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" docValues="false" />      
<field name="_childDocuments_" type="_nest_path_">
<field name="id" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="firstname" type="text_general"  indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="lastname" type="text_general"  indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

But seems `_nest_path_` field is not supported in solr 6.5 and getting error `Error loading class solr.NestPathField`.

Any alternatives to store child documents without using `nest_path` or is there something wrong that I am doing here?

This schema works perfectly fine in Solr 8.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child documents can be handled without using the nested documents feature - the [nested documents feature just makes it easier](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/indexing-nested-documents.html) and more automatic.

[Nested documents were introduced with Solr 8](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-12768) - so trying to use the feature with Solr 6 won't work as you've discovered.

In earlier versions, as far as I know, you'll have to make those updates manually with relevant fields referenced, then [apply the block join query parser](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/other-parsers.html#OtherParsers-BlockJoinParentQueryParser) and [childdoctransformer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/transforming-result-documents.html) explicitly with these values.

If you can, upgrade to Solr 8 (in the newest dotrelease) as the feature work's as you'd expect there, instead of adding the complexity of handling it yourself to work around the limitations in the earlier release.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have already figured out block join parser and child doc transformer for retrieving the results but what will i need to define in the managed schema for the nested structure ? Posting nested json doesnt work since there is no schema for nested fields. Can you share a sample of managed schema in the older version ? Upgrading is something that wont be preferred because of some dependecies.

Comment: There [are examples in the reference guide for 6.6, both for XML and JSON](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-NestedChildDocuments). In general, the child documents are included in a `_childDocuments_` element. You don't need anything specific in your managed schema for a nested structure - in effect there really isn't a structure, it's processed on the way out and in the queries to simulate a nested structure, more or less (and there is only one type of child documents included with each document).